# Not seeing the expected volume in a RAID 5

Tags: raid5

I have expanded a RAID 5 to include 12 - 3 TB drives.  I was expecting seeing a total of 33 TB in the RAID but only see 30 TB.  I do not have a hot spare.  Could 2 drives be reserved for parity?  This server is a Dell R510 with a H700 controller.  It function is my media server for Backupexec.  The OS is on a separate RAID 1.  The data RAID started with 7 - 3 TB drives.  Over the past 2 months I have been expanding the RAID one drive at a time to a total of 12 drives.

Comment: Are you sure it's RAID 5 and not RAID 6?

Answer (score 0):

raid 5 in this config should only be seeing 30TB usable space because 1/8 of the space must be used for parity.

you can find a raid  calculator also  by web search.